# More elegant way to decode \u0000 Unicode in an input stream

Tags: android, unicode

I'm parsing an input stream coming from Facebook. I'm using something like

```
BufferedReader in =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

And then `in.readLine` to actually read from the stream.

The stream seems to have Unicode characters already encoded in ASCII, so I see things like \u00e4 (with \u actually being two discrete ASCII characters). Right now, I'm fishing for "\u" and decoding the subsequent two hex bytes, turn them into a char and replace the string with them, which is obviously the worst way to do it.

I'm sure there's a cool way to use a native function to decode the special characters as the stream is being read (I was hoping it could be done on the InputStreamReader layer). But how?

Comment: What URL are you parsing, so we can see/verify your input? Is this JSON, by some chance?

Comment: It's Facebook's stupid new system with their graph API. Looks like of like this:

{"data":[{"name":"Thanatos","id":"1234"},{"name":"Max\u00e4","id":"5678"}]}

Comment: @Thanatos: Yes, it is, btw. And JSON's parser handles it properly. I suck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data format is JSON, which I didn't mention (and which Thanatos already assumed). Using Android's JSON parser will automatically decode the characters properly. Parsing JSON yourself is obviously a dumb idea on several levels.

Answer (score 2):

If you see '`\u00e4`' with the '`\`' and the '`u`' being separate, then the '`0`', '`0`', '`e`' and '`4`' probably make up the 4 hex digits of a 2 byte (16 bit) Unicode character.  The notation is based on C99; the alternative is '`\U00XXYYZZ`' where there are 8 hex digits representing a 32-bit UTF-32 character (but, because Unicode is a 21-bit code set, the first 2 of the 8 digits are always 0, and the next is often (usually) 0 too).

However, that doesn't answer your question about what's the right Android way to read the data, and you are right that there probably is one.

Comment: Yeah, it's essentially 6 bytes (well, physically 12 bytes, considering that it's inside a String, so each character is 2 bytes).

And my approach works fine - I read it as a 16-bit value and use it as a char. But since I'm doing this in Java and replacing the string as I go, there is tons of JVM and memory management overhead. Doing this natively while parsing would be infinitely faster.