# Appropriate charset for Android and Webservices

Tags: android, character-encoding

I have an app which retrieves user's data such as name, and sends it to a remote database thanks to web services.
I'm facing issues with special accents like in this name 'Tağıyeva'

The name is stored as Ta?ıyeva in the DB.

This is what I use to send data

```
static String postData(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, String url) {
        InputStream ips = null;
        try {
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection); 
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(MyInternetManager_Class.url+url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String contentAsString = isToString(ips);
            if (MyInternetManager_Class.debug) Log.e("recu",contentAsString);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200 || contentAsString.length() == 0) return "-1"; // erreur serveur
            else return contentAsString;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //...
        } 
        finally {
            try {if (ips != null) ips.close();} catch (IOException e){}
        }
    }
```

as you can see, I've let the default charset (which one is it?). My server is set in UTF-8. How to fix the problem?

**UPDATE:** now the JSON I receive looks like this
"name":"Nh\u00e1\u00ba\u00adt Pi\u00e1\u00bb\u00abn Ta\u00c4\u009f\u00c4\u00b1yeva"
I use it in order to convert InputStream to String

```
static String isToString(InputStream stream) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
```

But the string are not displayed correctly.
[image] instead of 'Nhật Piừn Tağıyeva'
How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
```

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to these docs, the [UrlEncodedFormEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) constructor you're using defaults to ISO-8559-1 charset. You can (and it looks like you should) pass the UTF-8 as a second parameter:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs),"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

> The data format is JSON, which I didn't mention (and which Thanatos already assumed). Using **Android's JSON parser** will automatically decode the characters properly. Parsing JSON yourself is obviously a dumb idea on several levels.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209912/more-elegant-way-to-decode-u0000-unicode-in-an-input-stream)

Comment: I'm already using JSONObject and JSONArray, thanks. The problem is that the name returned by the server isn't the same as the one stored in DB. I might make a mistake at this point. Check the very end of my question at the top.